# What practices exist for building a class library that handles all data operations?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, projects-and-solutions, class-library

I have a solution that contains 10 different WPF application projects and I am looking at refactoring them a little bit further.

Each of these projects have LINQ to SQL classes that provide access to many different databases and tables.  Fortunately, these LINQ to SQL classes are repeated many times across the projects so pulling them out into a class library seems to make a lot of sense.  So as far as questions go:

- Are there any base classes, interfaces, and/or design-patterns off of which I could build that assist in providing data? Conversely, what major pitfalls exist?
- What are the downsides to using a class library to centralize all data access for these projects? I.e., is there a better way?

Thanks for the help.